# React Native app keeps crashing on launching [Only on Android Oreo]

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with all versions of Oreo. When the app starts it asks for the overlay permission, I give it and then every time I open the app it just crashes immediately. It works on iOS and previous versions of Android.

**Updated Error:**

```
09-06 19:09:37.934 26719-26719/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    PID: 26719
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@6ac567e -- permission denied for window type 2003
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
```

**Old Error:**

```
09-06 14:20:14.200 4694-7991/com.google.android.gms E/MS_RegisterService: Exception during register request.
bods: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
at bodo.c(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):3)
at pge.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):93)
at com.google.android.libraries.matchstick.net.SilentRegisterIntentOperation.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):299)
at com.google.android.libraries.matchstick.net.SilentRegisterIntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):367)
at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):2)
at dfm.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):8)
at npz.a(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):9)
at dfr.run(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):10)
at dfo.run(:com.google.android.gms@12874026@12.8.74 (040700-204998136):9)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
```

Also my build.gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

compile project(':react-native-maps')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your app is trying to access something that it doesn't have permission. Try to add the permission in the androidMaifest.xml. The error stack isnt clear enough. What does your app do on the initial load?

Comment: @UmairAhmed actually nothing. It's absolutely basic app. There are two possibilities: it doesn't detect that I gave the permission for the overlay or it is for react-native-maps. Actually the react-native-maps is on a different screen and it works just fine on iOS and older versions of Android. That's why it's really strange and it's something that is coming with Oreo...

Comment: I have updated the error. It looks like it is from the overlay but don't know why...

Comment: Can you go to the settings on the device, Apps > [YOUR APP] > Permissions and make sure everything is granted

Comment: Yep, I checked several times and everything is looking good. Overlay permission is also set to "allowed".

Comment: Try running react-native-link again or remove mode modules and install them again

Comment: Already did that. But thank you for your suggestions. I am really thankful for your desire to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, I found that it's working just fine when builded for a release. It's not working only in Debug mode with Oreo versions. So maybe the problem is with the permissions of Overlay but android with Oreo versions somehow do not detect that the permission is given. But because it's working on iOS and all other Android versions and I had the chance to test it, debug it, etc. I can now just continue with submission process because it's working on Oreo versions as well but builded with the

`react-native run-android --variant=release`